# How to represent SQL Server type numeric(38,0) as IDL type (COM type library)?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, com, idl, typelib

How to represent SQL Server type `numeric(38,0)` as IDL type (COM type library)?

Thanks a lot for the help!

P.S. For example, SQL Server type `int` is `long` type in IDL.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could represent that type with IDL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers in COM could be:

- Integers up to 64 bits (`Int64`) - so up to 19 significant digits;
- Floating-point values up to 64 bit (`double`) - from 15 - 17 significant decimal digits precision.

So for 38 digits, none of those types would match your request. You can achieve the best resolution with `Int64`, but if your value is higher than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, you will reach an overflow.

I think the easier compliant type is a good old BSTR (`widestring`), in which you can store as many digit as wished - but encoded as plain text. On the code side, you will need to have a BCD library to process your high-resolution numbers: no Delphi native type (even `extended`) has such a resolution.

*Edit:* Another option (thanks Ondrej for the proposal) is an array of bytes. IMHO a COM binary array is less easy than a text content (and less efficient about speed, even if it uses less memory). Encoding option could be [good old BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). You may be able to find libraries on both sides of the COM object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the question was about IDL types (not Delphi types).

Comment: @Altaveron Why did you include the Delphi tag? I still don't see any reason why IDL can represent that type. What makes you think it can?

Comment: IDL is a generic term. I spoke about COM types. "Integers up to 64 bits", "Floating-point values up to 64 bit", and BSTR  are COM types. Since you put the "Delphi" tag in your question, I also named the Delphi types matching those COM types. There is a perfect match between those COM types and the Delphi types I named.

Comment: Another option is variant array of bytes.